# Is open set and interiority a necessary condition for differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, soft-question, definition, jacobian

I am going by what I am seeing on Wikipedia:  In 1D, the standard definition for differentiability is,

> A function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$, defined on an open set
> $U\subset\mathbb{R}$, is said to be ''differentiable'' at $a\in U$ if
> the derivative $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ exists.

Other times, $a$ is [defined to be](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/abbasc/math234-s05/Mth234SupMat12-3.pdf) a point which is in the interior of a not necessarily open domain.

However, when I read some other references such as Terence Tao's Analysis I, this assumption does not seem to exist and I don't think it is a mistake or an omission.

[image]

Can someone help me understand whether openness and interiority are necessary in order to define differentiability?

Comment: Roughly speaking, open sets in this context allow for two-sided derivatives, whereas closed sets have the limit points allowing for one-sided derivatives. Sequences taken within the metric balls either do or do not lie within the set and this restricts the directions.

Comment: No openness/interiority are not necessary, only that the point $a$ is an accumulation point of the domain (so that the limit $x\to a$ makes sense). The definition by Tao is simpy more general than the others.